# How to get conflicting lines with JGit

Tags: java, jgit

I'm developing the application, in which JGit is used.

After a pull, I have conflicting files. I can get it from

```java
List<String> list = git.status().call().getConflicting();
```

The list contains files in conflict.

I know, that I can get conflicting files from

```java
Map<String, int[][]> conflicts = git.pull().call().getMergeResult().getConflicts();
```

but it doesn't work if I restart my application. After the restart, I will have an empty map because I'm not able to redo the pull when the repository is in merging state.

How can I get conflicting lines by the name of file via JGit API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use a `ResolveMerger` to re-run the merge like so:

```java
ThreeWayMerger merger = StrategyResolve.newMerger(repository, true);
merger.merge(headCommit, fetchedCommit);
```

Note that the `MergeCommand` that is called during pull may use a different merge strategy. See MergeCommand ~ line 337 for details. However, make sure to create an *in-core* merger (the second argument must be `true`).

With `merger.getMergeResults()` you should be able to get the conflicting lines.

The whole approach, however, may fail because your work directory is already dirty with conflict markers (<<<<<<<<). Depending on your overall goal, I suggest reconsidering your approach to pull.

If you fetch changes from the upstream repository (without merging immediately) you can dry-run the merge as outlined above as often as necessary. The `FetchResult` returned by `FetchCommand::call()` contains information about the commit(s) that were fetched.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check it tommorow and write post.

Comment: It's work. Now, I try to understand API for MergeResult<?>. Thanks a lot