# Reset to specified commit using JGit

Tags: git, jgit

I'm using JGit to programmatically pull remote changes to a local repository. If the pull fails and throws an exception, I want to reset the local repository to the latest commit before the pull attempt.

However, the `ResetCommand` does not take a commit identifier as an argument, even though the Git reset command accepts a "commit" parameter. Is this a known limitation of the `ResetCommand`, or am I missing something?

Is there an alternative JGit command or sequence of commands that could be used to the same effect?

Comment: Can't test it right now, but did you try to use `setRef()` with the commitId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setRef()` method of the `ResetCommand` allows specifying the ID of a commit.
For example:

```
resetCommand.setRef("< SHA-1 >");
```

A pull can fail for several reasons. I assume that with 'pull fails and throws an exception' you refer to a pull that cannot be merged with the current local branch.

If your intention is to prevent a failing merge affecting the current repository state, you may want to first fetch the upstream changes and then 
follow the suggestion I made here: [How to get conflicting lines with JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792964/how-to-get-conflicting-lines-with-jgit/38795259#38795259)

Comment: The setRef() method was what I was looking for, I just didn't realize it accepts a commit id as a parameter (the API documentation does not mention this). I am actually stashing local changes before pulling, so I will never have conflicts. But the pull() method can also throw a GitAPIException if it fails for other reasons. It's unclear to me in which state the repository will be left if this happens, and this is why I am performing the reset.